# polymer slotted content and data binding

Tags: data-binding, polymer

Today, I'd like to create an element that generated a list of "cards". On these cards there could be very different things according to which page it gets included. For instance, sometimes these cards contain a picture, sometimes there could be contact information (name, age, adress, phone...), sometimes it could contain only a video, etc...

So what my idea was to design a polymer element that handle the CSS, the ajax call to the datasource, the dom-repeat, and a `<slot>` (formerly known as `<content>`) which would include in this element the html template used to create the card content (picture, video, or contact card)

this is what I did so far:

Parent element:

```
<tiles-list id="tilesView" datas="[[datas]]">
  <img src="https//lorempixel.com/200/130/people" />
  <p>[[item.name]]</p>
  <p>[[item.age]]</p>
  <p>[[item.adress]]</p>
  <p>[[item.phone]]</p>
</tiles-list>
```

`{{datas}}`is replaced by the URL for the ajax call

and in the child element:

```
<iron-ajax
  auto
  url="[[datas]]"
  handle-as="json"
  last-response="{{ajax}}"
  on-response="log"></iron-ajax>

<div id="grid">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajax.data]]">
    <div class="card gridCell">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

But yeah, it doesn't work. All I get is a list with the right amount of cards, but only the first one contains a picture, but no data. So I guess the slot doesn't work like I'm trying to make it work, and the data binding cannot work this way either.

Anybody has a solution?

Comment: You are right. As far as i know you cannot keep `slot/content` in a `dom-repeat` and then have multiple copies of it. One solution will be to move `dom-repeat` itself to `light-dom`

Comment: well, putting the dom repeat in light dom is precisely what i'm trying to avoid. If I do so, I cannot create this wonderful generic element that will turn any html code into cards

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to achive is a perfect case for the [Templatizer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Templatizer).
Change your code to:

```
<tiles-list id="tilesView" datas="[[datas]]">
     <template tile>
        <img src="https//lorempixel.com/200/130/people" />
        <p>[[item.name]]</p>
        <p>[[item.age]]</p>
        <p>[[item.adress]]</p>
        <p>[[item.phone]]</p>
    </template>
</tiles-list>
```

And then when your ajax request resolves do something like this:

```
var template = Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('template[tile]');
this.templatize(template);
ajax.data.forEach(function(item){
    var instance = this.stamp(item);
    Polymer.dom(this.$.grid).appendChild(instance.root);
});
```

This will create several instances of you template, no dom-repeat needed.

Comment: This stamps a template for each `data`.
But are the stamped instance really bound to the `data`?
Not in my understanding.
"As this library does not retain references to templates instanced by the user, it is the templatize owner's responsibility to forward host property changes into user-stamped instances."
([see the docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/api/utils/templatize))

Comment: That is correct there is no Data Binding. Once you have new data you need to restamp your data to it.